# hp printer not digitalizing

Tags: drivers

I'M on ubuntu 14.04.
I have installed my hp officejet 4636 using drivers that came with the system, not those from HP.The printer is printing but I can't digitalize any document and I get a message on  the printer saying that drivers are not installed. I made some research and went to the HP site.I found their instructions to install in ubuntu but most of the commands are not correct.
Can someone please give me a detailed information on how to install hp drivers correctly.??

Comment: Please post the link to the HP site you speak of...

Comment: here it is:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html

Comment: it starts just with first commande they present:sh hplip-3.16.11.run I get an error: command not found

Comment: how did you run it `chmod +x hplip-3.16.11.run` then `./hplip-3.16.11.run`

Comment: No, I entered only : " sh hplip-3.16.11.run " just like it's written on their picture.

Comment: Try it this way and lets see

Comment: I solved the problem.Selecting the scanning on the computer instead of doing it on the printer works great.Tks for your time.